# Can we switch integral and expectation by Fubini's theorem?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

From [Itō isometry Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_isometry):

[image]

Can we switch the expectation and integral in the RHS by Fubini's theorem?

I'm actually not quite sure how Fubini's theorem is used outside [basic Calculus](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/fubini-s-theorem-and-evaluating-double-integrals-over-rectan).

The fact that my professor did not discuss [Riemann integration of a random variable](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2004/notes/l6.pdf) suggests that it is possible otherwise the $\int_0^T X_t^2 dt$ probably wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch expectation and integral by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) since $X_s^2\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks Alex R. Do we ever have to adjust the region of integration as is done for non-rectangular regions in R2 for riemann integration in basic calculus?

Comment: @bclc: no, the region is rectangular

Comment: Is it? One is from 0 to T while the other is not over an interval but rather over $\Omega$

Comment: @BCLC: yes, which is still a rectangle. Easier said, the two integral are decoupled

Comment: Never mind. I'll ask about that in another question sometime. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a result from Itô isometry in Stochastic Calculus, where LHS is the variance of the Random Variable $\int_{0}^{T}X_tdW_t$, reduced to ordinary expectation w.r.t $ds$ on RHS.

Comment: What do you mean? My question is about RHS: is it equal to int (e(x^2))dt? Then the answer appears to be yes by fubini's or tonelli's theorem